# how to expand and collapse div container on populated content

Tags: html, css

i have a div that in some cases may be populated with a video. I tried to use

```
height:auto;
```

on the container div but when the video appears it passes outside the div container.
A fixed height solves the problem, but leaves a large area when the video does not appear.

Comment: Is that video inside an iframe?

Comment: i already tried a min-height, still leaves a large gap when the video doesn't appear, the video is activated by JavaScript, no iFrame

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please, a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or stack snippet would be good.

Comment: Please update on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/692u08a2/1/).
I tried both the situations but it was working fine.

Comment: none of these work, but this is what i have:

   <div id="video_container">

   <div class="bgvideo"></div>

   <div id="video">video appears here </div>

   </div>

the bgvideo is the background of the div that contains the color and curved corners

the video container holds everything together and the video div holds the video itself

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the two options listed below.

[You can view the JSFiddle here. I also provide more comments within the JSFiddle to help guide you better.](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gjrtye/2/)

Option 1 - Leave the height of that div holding the video blank and CSS will adjust automatically.

CSS:

```
.videoDivOption1 {
    /* blank */
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="videoDivOption1">
    The text represents your video. Once your delete the text it represents no video.
</div>
```

Or you can use min-height for that div, but the parent div must have a property of `height:100%;` or the min-height will not work.

CSS:

```
.videoDivOption2_Container {
    height:100%;
    }

 .videoDivOption2 {
    min-height:0px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="videoDivOption2_Container">
    <div class="videoDivOption2">
        The text represents your video. Once your delete the text it represents no video.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working for me, i think its because i have a third div that acts as the background with curved corners, so what would i apply to the third div that would rest inside the container itself?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a min-height also for this div in which video appears for expmple

```
 height:auto;
 min-height:50px; /* or something else*/
```